How to install Tizen wgt build directly on Tv or create tmg build from wgt
How can we create the tmg build from wgt build, earlier we used to use USB Demo Packing Tool to convert the wgt build to tmg build but now this tool is not available in Samsung seller portal.
I tried to install the wgt build to Tv directly by opening the developer mode in tv and adding all the necessary configurations but when I try to connect the device from Tizen Studio device manager then I faced this issue:
The remote device is already connected by another one.
This remote device is running on a non-standard port.
There is no IP address, please check the physical connection
Can anyone tell me how can I install the build to SamsungTv directly so that I can test my app there before deploying it to seller portal

can you check if the tool to convert the WGT file to TMG and license file is still present to date on the Samsung Seller Portal?
Go to Tools > USB Demo Packaging Tool
Also, if you wish to run directly onto the TV, you will need to use CLI commands by Tizen to do so. Samsung has provided steps to build your package and run it on a projected TV device.
https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/web-tools/cli

The remote device is already connected by another one. This remote device is running on a non-standard port. There is no IP address, please check the physical connection   -
First of all, you will need to be in same network for your development system and TV, and enter your system IP in TV
